# Как разделить большой xml-файл размеров 1 гб на множество по 20 мб?

Tags: python, xml

Мне дали большой xml-файл, который мне требуется импортировать на сайт, но компонент отвечающий за импорт принимает только файлы меньше 20 МБ. Можно ли с помощью алгоритма на python из одного большого xml-файла достать все данные и равномерно распределить на множество небольших по 20 и меньше мегабайт?

Под "равномерно распределить" я имею ввиду что бы файл заканчивался на `</root>` и в один файл не попадал `</root>` и его дочерние элементы из другого файла. Каждый блок весит от силы полмегабайта-мегабайт.

Пример одного блока в файле:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <Big_Images>
    <item>path/to/img1.jpg</item>
    <item>path/to/img2.jpg</item>
    <item>path/to/img3.jpg</item>
  </Big_Images> 
  <Title>
    <item>Название</item>
  </Title>
  <Main_Info>
    <item>Около 50-100 строк html кода</item>
  </Main_Info>
  <Package_Weight>
    <item>Product weight: 1.2 kg</item>
    <item>Package weight: 1.3 kg</item>
  </Package_Weight>
  <Package_Content></Package_Content>
</root>
```

Comment: У вас есть агрантия, что любой блок в этом XML не больше 20мб?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree

data = """
<root>
  <Big_Images>
    <item>path/to/img1.jpg</item>
    <item>path/to/img2.jpg</item>
    <item>path/to/img3.jpg</item>
  </Big_Images> 
  <Title>
    <item>Название</item>
  </Title>
  <Main_Info>
    <item>Около 50-100 строк html кода</item>
  </Main_Info>
  <Package_Weight>
    <item>Product weight: 1.2 kg</item>
    <item>Package weight: 1.3 kg</item>
  </Package_Weight>
  <Package_Content></Package_Content>
</root>
"""

data = data*3  # Для пример будет 3 одинаковых дерева <root>

class Saver:
    name = '/путь/к/название_файла_{}.xml'  # Скобки '{}' - место для счетчика.
    start_id = 0
    nblocks = 2  # << Кол-во блоков на один файл.
    _cur_block_id = 0
    _cur_block_str = ''

    def __call__(self, data):
        if self._cur_block_id < self.nblocks:
            self._cur_block_id += 1
            self._cur_block_str = '\n'.join([self._cur_block_str, data])
        else:
            name = self.name.format(self.start_id)
            self.start_id += 1
            with open(name, 'w') as f:
                f.write(self._cur_block_str)
            self._cur_block_id = 1
            self._cur_block_str = data

    def __del__(self):  # Обрати внимание, что последний файл будет записываться при удалении объекта saver.
        name = self.name.format(self.start_id)
        self.start_id += 1
        with open(name, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self._cur_block_str)

data = f'<roots>{data}</roots>' # Т.к. у нас получается битый xml (множество одинаковых тегов в корне)
parsed = etree.fromstring(data).findall('root')

saver = Saver()

for i in parsed:
    saver(etree.tostring(i, encoding='unicode'))

del saver  # Это удаляет объект saver и сохраняет последний файл.
```

Не забудь убрать: `data = data*3`
При проблемах с кодировкой на Windows, замените `'w'` на `'ab'` в `open` и удалите `encoding='unicode'` из `tostring`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97170/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-abrosimov----xml--).

Comment: Имя файла подкорректировал? `name = '/tmp/блок_{}.xml'`? Скобки `{}` в нем есть? Воткни `print(name)` после `f.write(self._cur_block_str)` и посмотри, куда запись идет. `nblocks = 2` - количество блоков `<root>` на один файл не слишком большое?